# a program that can calculate exponentiation

Tags: c++, math

I've tried to create a small program that could calculate a raised to the power of b and I get these errors.. Can you please tell me what I should change and what is wrong

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{
int a,b;
cout<<"a="<<endl;
cin>>a;
cout<<"b="<<endl;
cin>>b;
 cout<<"a la puterea b este: "<<pow(a,b)<<endl;

getch();


}
```

Comment: "these errors" - So what errors?

Comment: Also, here's a non-exhaustive list of things that are obviously wrong at first glance: `using namespace std;`, `#include <math.h>`, the `c` tag, the indentation, and the fact that you're using `pow()` to calculate powers of integers.

Comment: error C2668: 'pow' : ambiguous call to overloaded function

Comment: IntelliSense: more than one instance of overloaded function "pow" matches the argument list

Answer (score 1):

In C++98, there are following `pow` functions:

```
double pow (double base     , double exponent);
float pow (float base      , float exponent);
long double pow (long double base, long double exponent);
double pow (double base     , int exponent);
long double pow (long double base, int exponent);
```

You can see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/).

Please try typecasting a into any of these like

```
 pow((double)a, b);
```